# HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found at root folder

Tags: java, hibernate, runtime-error

I tried to run easy test for Hibernate testing but it fails:

```
public class TestService {
    static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mail = "lelyak@gmail.com";
        User user = new UserService().getByEmail(mail);
        System.out.println("user info: " + user.toString());
        System.out.println("\nTHE END");
    }
}
```

Here is output:

```
02:24:53,166 ERROR main HibernateUtil:<clinit>:24 - org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lelyak.controller.dao.ElementDAOImpl.getAllElements(ElementDAOImpl.java:76)
    at com.lelyak.controller.service.UserService.getListOfObjects(UserService.java:39)
    at com.lelyak.controller.service.UserService.getByEmail(UserService.java:52)
    at com.lelyak.application.TestService.main(TestService.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

**HibernateUtil**:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    static {
        try {
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .buildServiceRegistry());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

`cfg` file is at project folder:

[image]

`log4j.properties` at the same location is readable. What is wrong with `cfg` file?

Any suggestion?

Comment: try `/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to read the file present in folder `WebContent`,you could try to use likes this

```
InputStream st= getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

But I recommend to put `hibernate.cfg.xml` under src and your code

```
 configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate pulls it's `hibernate.cfg.xml` from the class path rather than the file system. So if you put it in `src` or `src\Java` depending on your structure it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your hibernate.cfg.xml under the src folder and in your code you can do this

```
 configuration.configure();
```